# function checking if record exists in database

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to create a function in java that takes an email, checks if its found in the database and returns a boolean. Thank you in advance.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
while (true)
 {
   a.QueryDataFromDB(this.Email, Email,  this.TableName, "email");
   if (a.QueryDataFromDB(this.Email, Email,  this.TableName, "email")==""){                
            break;
        }
  else {          
         System.out.println("This email has already been used. Please use another email.");
         email = uin.nextLine();                
        }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Do you get an error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what `a.QueryDataFromDB()` query should return, but it looks like that you want to compare it with empty string. If it true, you should use `equals()` function:

```
a.QueryDataFromDB(this.Email, Email,  this.TableName, "email").equals("")
```

Comment: a.QueryDataFromDB() is supposed to return a string that has the email from the database

Comment: so you have to use .equals() and not ==